# vba copy SINGLE column filter to another column in same sheet

Tags: vba, autofilter

I want to move Column F to Column S (re-order columns) in a sheet and retain Column F's filters.  I can copy/paste or move Column F values into Column S, but I don't see a way to carry over the filter. The .AutoFilter method may be my only choice, but it seems difficult to use when applying to a new column that doesn't already have a filter.

Am I taking completely the wrong approach?

Is there no straightforward method to grabbing one column's filter info and applying it to a new column that doesn't currently have a filter?  Do you have to activate the new column's filter first?  If so, does this require saving all column filter info, turning off .AutoFilterMode, turning it back on, and then re-applying all filters while extending the range to include the new column?

I can't even get the autofilter to reset (results in 400 error):

```
Sub extend_autofilter()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

If ws.AutoFilterMode = True Then

    With ws
        .Range("B2:S20").AutoFilter
        .Range("B2:S20").AutoFilter
    End With
Else
    With ws
        .Range("B2:S20").AutoFilter
    End With
End If End Sub
```

Comment: Do you only need the filtered data? If so, copy that first elsewhere then into an array and re-arrange the columns in a loop  dumping to the sheet per column or into another array then back to sheet as possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  No, I need to keep ALL data in individual columns as well as the filter for each of the columns when I re-order them.  This is part of a larger macro, for which re-ordering filtered columns is just one part.  Seems that accessing a single column's filter values is really uncommon (or really easy) and therefore not a common topic of discussion.

Comment: There are a couple of SO questions and answers I have seen on storing filters and restoring them.

Comment: The ones I have seen all involve iterating over the .AutoFilter object (?) and storing each existing filter in an array.  Then, you run your macro, and then you iterate back over the array to restore.  Using this approach, I can't figure out how to determine a filter's old column and then apply it to a different, new column that didn't previously exist in the array.